# "NA" in JSON file translates to NA logical

Tags: json, r, dataframe, jsonlite

I have `json` files with data for countries. One of the files has the following data:

```
"[{\"count\":1,\"subject\":{\"name\":\"Namibia\",\"alpha2\":\"NA\"}}]"
```

I have the following code convert the `json` into a `data.frame` using the `jsonlite` package:

```
df = as.data.frame(fromJSON(jsonfile), flatten=TRUE))
```

I was expecting a `data.frame` with numbers and strings:

```
count subject.name subject.alpha2
1      Namibia             "NA"
```

Instead, the `NA` alpha2 code is being automatically converted into `NA` logical, and this is what I get:

```
str(df)
$ count         : int 1
$ subject.name  : chr "Namibia"
$ subject.alpha2: logi NA
```

I want alpha2 to be a string, not logical. How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. good first question. Try adding some more sample data which people can play with.

Comment: Just coerce to `character`. It's probably not necessary to do so because R will do that coercion at the first need.

Comment: @BondedDust Thanks. Yeah, R does the coercion at first need, but there are some files with just data for Namibia. Is there a way to coerce to `character` when converting the json to `dataframe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular implementation of fromJSON (and there are three different packages with that name for a function) has a simplifyVector argument which appears to prevent the corecion:

```
 require(jsonlite)

> as.data.frame( fromJSON(test, simplifyVector=FALSE ) )
  count subject.name subject.alpha2
1     1      Namibia             NA
> str( as.data.frame( fromJSON(test, simplifyVector=FALSE ) ) )
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ count         : int 1
 $ subject.name  : Factor w/ 1 level "Namibia": 1
 $ subject.alpha2: Factor w/ 1 level "NA": 1
> str( as.data.frame( fromJSON(test, simplifyVector=FALSE ) ,stringsAsFactors=FALSE) )
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ count         : int 1
 $ subject.name  : chr "Namibia"
 $ subject.alpha2: chr "NA"
```

I tried seeing if that option worked well with the `flatten` argument, but was disappointed:

```
> str(  fromJSON(test, simplifyVector=FALSE, flatten=TRUE) )
List of 1
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ count  : int 1
  ..$ subject:List of 2
  .. ..$ name  : chr "Namibia"
  .. ..$ alpha2: chr "NA"
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did not solve my use case.
However, `rjson::fromJSON` does this naturally, and to my surprise, 10 times faster on my data.